# If a relation $R$ on a set $A$ contains $n$ pairs, what is the greatest amount of pairs $R \circ R$ can have?

Tags: graph-theory, relations

I have attempted various methods, but I am stuck, so I will ask here. I really wanted to solve this myself but I can't. If you have a solution, maybe try providing only a hint, but if you want to post the full solution that is fine too.

Based on my work, it seems to be $\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}$ if n is odd, and $\dfrac{(n+2)^2}{4}$ if it is even. I have proven it is a lower bound, since an example exists, but not that it is the maximum.

For the example relation I found for odd $n$, the family of digraphs of the relation looks like a sort of jellyfish, with one vertex having an edge towards itself and the other vertices pointing to and away from that vertex.

The adjacency matrix has 1s completely filling the first row and column and 0s everywhere else. Hence, for example, for 4 vertices we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Then the square (under boolean multiplication) is a fully-filled matrix of 16 1s. However, if we increase the size of the matrix (while keeping 7 1s) it might be possible to get more than 16, which I have no idea how to prove.

Comment: One way to obtain bounds can be to use Cauchy-Schwartz's inequality, with $x^TA^TAx$. You mention $n$ pairs, but your $4\times 4$ example has $7$ ones, instead of $4$. Are your pairs counted as both directions? Is your relation symmetric?

Comment: When I said pairs, I meant pairs of elements of $A$. i.e. for $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ a relation $R$ of cardinality 7 where $R\circ R$ is of big cardinality could be $\{(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,1), (3,1), (4,1)\}$ (the square is then $A×A$). Sorry for the ambiguity. Oh, and the amount of pairs and size of A can be different. Oh, I see... I miswrote 7 instead of 4. Sorry about that...